# Select shows value in input AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to do something like this : When you select ex. "login", then in input text shows `login` from `$scope.logins` The same with `password`

JS:

```
  $scope.logins = [{
        "login" : "log",
        "password" : "pass"
    }]
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="type">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
     <option>login</option>
     <option>password</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="value" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
```

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Why did you remove my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-change` for this:

```
<select ng-model="type" ng-change="onSelectBoxChange(type)">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
     <option value="login">login</option>
     <option value="password">password</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="value" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
```

**In Controller**

```
$scope.logins = [{
        "login" : "log",
        "password" : "pass"
    }];

$scope.onSelectBoxChange = function(selectedValue){
  if(selectedValue=="login"){
    $scope.value = $scope.logins[0].login;
  }else{
    $scope.value=undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this became the accepted answer, this won't even work for both cases?

Answer (score 2):

**First Method**

You can use `$scope.$watch` to accomplish this

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.logins = [{
        "login" : "log",
        "password" : "pass"
    }]
    $scope.$watch('type',function(val){
       $scope.value=$scope.logins[0][val];
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController" class="col-xs-12">
<select ng-model="type">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
     <option>login</option>
     <option>password</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="value" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> 
</div>
```

**Second Method**

You can directly bind the logins object with respect to type in your input. (No calculations needed in js)

```js
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.logins = [{
        "login" : "log",
        "password" : "pass"
    }]

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainController" class="col-xs-12">
<select ng-model="type">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
     <option>login</option>
     <option>password</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="logins[0][type]" style="margin-bottom:5px;"> 
</div>
```