# Show value in input AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to do something like this : When you select ex. "login", then in input text shows `login` from `$scope.logins` . The same with `password`

JS:

```
   $scope.logins = [{
            "login" : "log",
            "password" : "pass"
        }]


    $scope.onSelectBoxChange = function(selectedValue){
     if(selectedValue=="login"){
    $scope.value = $scope.logins[0].login;
     }else{
    $scope.value=undefined;
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
 <ul>

      <li><button ng-model="type" ng-change="onSelectBoxChange(type)">login</button>
      </li>
      <li><button ng-model="type" ng-change="onSelectBoxChange(type)">password</button>
      </li>
 </ul>

<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="value" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
```

My code doesn't work.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: In the button tag you should use ng-click not ng-change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select shows value in input AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458970/select-shows-value-in-input-angularjs)

Comment: pls write your working code , and also if any error coming .

Answer (score 0):

You have used ng-change. Instaed you should use ng-click, ad button fires click event.

```
 <ul>
      <li><button ng-model="type" ng-click="onSelectBoxChange(type)">login</button>
      </li>
      <li><button ng-model="type" ng-click="onSelectBoxChange(type)">password</button>
      </li>
 </ul>
<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="value" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Anita, the ng-change should be changed to ng-click.
ng-change is used for elements like dropdown, where there is an action involved when there is a change in value. DUring the click event, there is no such change in the value, hence there wont be any function implementation.