# Dropdown menu shows value in input AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to do something like this : When you click ex. "login" in `<ul class="dropdown-menu">`, then in input text shows `login` from `$scope.logins` The same with `password`

```
$scope.logins = [{
        "login" : "log",
        "password" : "pass"
    }]
```

HTML :

```
  <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Type
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><button>login</button></li>
                 <li><a>password</a></li>
                </ul>
               </div>

<input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="value" ng-model="value">
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What is the issue? What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select shows value in input AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458970/select-shows-value-in-input-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Try add `ng-click` to `li` tag and init `value` model.

```
  <li ng-click="value = logins[0].login"><a >login</a></li>
  <li ng-click="value = logins[0].password"><a >password</a></li>
```

Comment: I don't want to put 'login' to value, i want to put logins.login

Comment: update to this `<li ng-click="value = logins[0].login"><a >login</a></li>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="script.js"></script>

<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Type
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul ng-init="placeholder = ''" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-click="placeholder = 'login'"><a>login</a></li>
        <li ng-click="placeholder = 'password'"><a>password</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <input class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-model="value">
  </div>
```